# Python index error value not in list...on .index(value)

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am a beginner at Python, and to those who holds negative thoughts against my post, please leave. I am simply seeking help here and trying to learn. I'm trying to check within a simple data set the 0s and 1s. This will be used towards defining voids and solids on floor plans to define zones in buildings... eventually 0s and 1s will be swapped out with coordinates.

I am getting this error: ValueError: [0, 3] is not in list

I am simply checking if one list is contained in the other.

```
currentPosition's value is  [0, 3]
subset, [[0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 1], [3, 1], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7]]
```

Here's the code snippet:

```
def addRelationship(locale, subset):
    subset = []; subSetCount = 0
    for rowCount in range(0, len(locale)):
        for columnCount in range (0, int(len(locale[rowCount])-1)):
            height = len(locale)
            width = int(len(locale[rowCount]))
            currentPosition = [rowCount, columnCount]
            currentVal = locale[rowCount][columnCount]
            print "Current position is:" , currentPosition, "=", currentVal

            if (currentVal==0 and subset.index(currentPosition)):
                subset.append([rowCount,columnCount])
                posToCheck = [rowCount, columnCount]
                print "*********************************************Val 0 detected, sending coordinate to check : ", posToCheck

                newPosForward = checkForward(posToCheck)
                newPosBackward = checkBackward(posToCheck)
                newPosUp = checkUpRow(posToCheck)
                newPosDown = checkDwnRow(posToCheck)
```

I am using subset.index(currentPosition) to check and see if [0,3] is in subset but getting the [0,3] is not in list. How come?

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Comment: What should this strange code do? Please bring your problem to a  minimal and understandable test set. Stackoverflow is not about please-decipher-my-code.

Comment: You set `subset=[]` and then never append anything to it until after an `.index` call.  How could that first `.index` call *not* raise a ValueError?  `subset` is always going to be empty by construction.

Comment: @DSM: It shoudl raise a `ValueError`.

Comment: @Maulwurfn: I just started coding Python, literally yesterday... if you do not want to help, go elsewhere and leave people alone... thanks for ruining my day

Comment: @user1518600: To be fair to Maulwurfn, this block of code is pretty cryptic. If you explain your algorithm, chances are someone will suggest a *better* way to accomplish the same thing. This is especially applicable in your case, as a new python coder.

Comment: @Joel, I sort of see where both of you are coming from. Both have good points but it did make me very uncomfortable when someone was quick to judge and labeled me with a tag. This is an open community and the least anyone can do is to treat everyone else with courtesy and not in a condescending tone. People share and thrive and grow together in this community including experts as well. Keeping an open dialogue is positive instead of shutting others down with negativity. That's how I feel but of course he may feel otherwise.

Comment: @Joel, thanks for trying to be a peace maker tho.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let's show some equivalent code that throws the same error.

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = [[2,3],[4,5]]

# Works correctly, returns 0
a.index([1,2])

# Throws error because list does not contain it
b.index([1,2])
```

If all you need to know is whether something is contained in a list, use the keyword `in` like this.

```
if [1,2] in a:
    pass
```

Alternatively, if you need the exact position but don't know if the list contains it, you can catch the error so your program does not crash.

```
index = None

try:
    index = b.index([0,3])
except ValueError:
    print("List does not contain value")
```

Comment: If you need to capture the index, you should assign it to a variable in the `try` and assign `None` in the `except`.

Comment: If you do the `None` assignment in the `except` clause, you skip one assignment operation in the case that an index exists.  Yes premature optimization is usually something to avoid, but I think in this case, it also makes the code more explicit.

Comment: This is a trivial issue, but I prefer to keep creation of variables outside of conditionals just for clarity.  It's probably a style I've kept from coding in C, but it makes me more comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

Why complicate things

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
val1 = [3,4]
val2 = [2,5]
```

check this

```
a.index(val1) if val1 in a else -1
a.index(val2) if val2 in a else -1
```

Comment: This cannot be used as index -1 refers to the last element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

`subset.index(currentPosition)` evaluates `False` when `currentPosition` is at index 0 of `subset`, so your `if` condition fails in that case.  What you want is probably:

```
...
if currentVal == 0 and currentPosition in subset:
...
```

Comment: Good catch, but I think that's only part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that

```
list = [1,2,3]

for item in range(len(list)):
    print(item)
```

won't work because it starts at 0, so you need to write

```
for item in range(1, len(list)):
    print(item)
```