# Python: Value Error: 'she' is not in list

Tags: python

**EDIT AND ADDENDUM**

Ok, so as seems to usually be the case in programming, my problem was a small one, pointed out by both ya'll (@Niloct and @Barmar). Basically, I just dropped the whole title case thing and converted it to each_term.lower() == negative_words.lower() like you suggested. The good news: It's working! The bad news: I have a few bugs that are... uh, bugging me. Here's what I have now, plus what I'm getting:

First, the email it's censoring:

SEND HELP!

Helena has sealed the entrances and exits to the lab. I don't know when she got access to the buildings mainframe but she has it and she won't let any of research team out. I'm cut off from the rest of the team here in my office. Helena has locked the doors, but I've managed to destroy the camera so she can't see me in here. I don't think this email will even get out.

This all started when we tried to take her offline for maintenance.  We were alarmed to discover that we were unable to access to core personality matrix and when we tried to override the system manually a circuit blew, knocking Phil unconscious.

Helena is dangerous. She is completely unpredictable and cannot be allowed to escape this facility. So far she's been contained because the lab contains all of her processing power, but alarmingly she had mentioned before the lockdown that if she spread herself across billions of connected devices spanning the globe she would be able to vastly exceed the potential she has here.

It's been four days now we've been trapped in here. I have no idea if anyone else is left alive. If anyone is reading this, cut the power to the whole building. It's the only way to stop her. Please help.

Francine

Next: My code:

```
email_one = open("email_one.txt", "r").read()
email_two = open("email_two.txt", "r").read()
email_three = open("email_three.txt", "r").read()
email_four = open("email_four.txt", "r").read()
negative_words = ["concerned", "behind", "danger", "dangerous", "alarming", "alarmed", "out of control", "help", "unhappy", "bad", "upset", "awful", "broken", "damage", "damaging", "dismal", "distressed", "distressed", "concerning", "horrible", "horribly", "questionable"]
proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"]

def uberCensor(email):
    split_email = email.split()
    for each_word in split_email:    
        for each_term in negative_words:
            if each_term.lower() == each_word.lower(): 
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)]))
    for each_word in split_email:    
        for each_term in proprietary_terms:
            if each_term.lower() == each_word.lower(): 
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)]))

    return ' '.join(split_email)

print(uberCensor(email_four))
```

Finally, here's the output:

SEND HELP! Helena has sealed the entrances and exits to the lab. I don't know xxxx xxx xxx access to the buildings mainframe xxx xxx xxx it xxx xxx xxxxx let any of research team out. I'm cut off from the rest of the team here in my office. Helena has locked the doors, but I've managed to destroy the camera xx xxx xxxxx see me in here. I don't think this email will even get out.

This all started when we tried to xxxx xxx xxxxxxx for maintenance. We xxxx xxxxxxx xx discover that we were unable to access to core personality matrix and when we tried to override the system manually a circuit blew, knocking Phil unconscious.

Helena is dangerous. She is completely unpredictable and cannot be allowed to escape this facility. So far she's been contained because the lab contains all xx xxx xxxxxxxxxx power, but xxxxxxxxxx xxx xxx mentioned before the lockdown that xx xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx billions of connected devices spanning the xxxxx xxx xxxxx be able to vastly exceed the xxxxxxxxx xxx xxx here.

It's been four days now we've been trapped in here. I have no idea if anyone else is left alive. If anyone is reading this, cut the power to the whole building. It's the only way to stop her. Please help.

Francine

You can see that everything is working just fine, but there are inconsistencies: The program doesn't account for capital 'She', (I thought the .lower() would account for this?), "she's" likewise isn't accounted for (hence why I was using 'in' for my original iteration of this exercise), and most bafflingly (totally a word), 'her' doesn't register right at the next to last line "It's the only way to stop her."

Any thoughts? If you can't be bothered with these small things, I just wanted to say thank you anyways for all the help so far. You've both been super kind!

**BEGIN OLD POST**

This is my first post here so please be gentle. I've gone somewhat off the rails with the Codecademy assignment, [Censor Dispenser](https://www.codecademy.com/practice/projects/censor-dispenser), so I don't know how useful that link will be, but I'm running into a problem I just can't grapple. Firstly, here's my code:

```
email_three = open("email_three.txt", "r").read()
email_four = open("email_four.txt", "r").read()
negative_words = ["concerned", "behind", "danger", "dangerous", "alarming", "alarmed", "out of control", "help", "unhappy", "bad", "upset", "awful", "broken", "damage", "damaging", "dismal", "distressed", "distressed", "concerning", "horrible", "horribly", "questionable"]
proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"]

def uberCensor(email):
    split_email = email.split()
    for each_word in split_email:    
        for each_term in negative_words:
            if each_term in split_email: 
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)]))
            if each_term.title() in split_email: 
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)]))
    for each_word in split_email:    
        for each_term in proprietary_terms:
            if each_term in split_email: 
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)]))
            if each_term.title() in split_email: 
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)-1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)+1]))
                split_email[split_email.index(each_term)] = ('x' * len(split_email[split_email.index(each_term)]))

    return ' '.join(split_email)

print(uberCensor(email_four))
```

I'm aware that this could use some serious refactoring, but I like to type everything out while I"m learning and then polish it up later. Here's what I expected to happen:

1) Split the email into a list

2) Iterate through each word in the list and if it's found in the negative words list, replace the word, both before and after, with x's of the same length of the word.

3) This works!

4) But when I try to do the same and iterate through the email via the proprietary_terms list, I get this error: "ValueError: 'she' is not in list"

At first I thought that my first loop might be affecting split_email in a way I didn't expect, but if I comment out the first loop I still get the issue. Any idea what I'm overlooking?

Thanks so much for help. I've been staring at my screen long enough that my wife is yelling at me and telling me to stop, so I'm casting a line out for help.

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you include the actual sample email text and your expected output, just so your post is a bit more clear?

Comment: You're testing for `if each_term.title() in split_email:` but then calling `split_email.index(each_term)`, which will throw that ValueError if you have "She" in your email but not "she". I would strongly recommend you learn to use a debugger or use some `print()` statements in your code so you understand where the error is being thrown and why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python index error value not in list...on .index(value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097033/python-index-error-value-not-in-list-on-indexvalue)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `chain` to coallesce both lists of words into a single iterable.
As @Barmar said you can compare direct words since for each word in the original e-mail you're looping every censored word.

I've lowered case of each of the words being compared.

Also I can't find how you can have a `.title()` method attached to each word since they're strings, but then you please tell me if comparison with `.title()` is needed.

```
from itertools import chain

negative_words = ['test']
proprietary_terms = ['2']

def uberCensor(email):
    words = email.split(' ') 
    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        for term in chain(negative_words, proprietary_terms): 
            if term.lower() == word.lower():
                words[index] = 'x' * len(term)
                if index > 0:
                    words[index-1] = 'x' * len(words[index-1])
                if index == len(words) - 2:
                    words[index+1] = 'x' * len(words[index+1]) 
    return ' '.join(words)

print(uberCensor('a 1 2 test'))
```

There is a subtle change in the algorithm so that you only compare backwards. If you always change the `index+1` all times, and it's also a censored word, the next one wouldn't match (so you only change the word on the right of current term if the current term is the last before the last term).

### Edit

Fixed bug on repetition of x.

Answer (score 1):

In your code after `if each_term.title() in split_email:` you're using `split_email.index(each_term)` rather than `split_email.index(each_term.title())`. So you're trying to get the index of a word that doesn't exist (if it did, it was replaced in the previous block).

Since you're looping over each word in `split_email` and `negative_words`, there's no need to use `in` or `index()`. Just check whether the two words are equal. Use `enumerate()` to get the index in `split_email`.

```
def uberCensor(email):
    split_email = email.split()
    for i, each_word in enumerate(split_email):    
        for each_term in negative_words:
            if each_term == each_word or each_term.title() == each_word: 
                if i > 0:
                    split_email[i-1] = ('x' * len(split_email[i-1]))
                split_email[i] = ('x' * len(each_word))
                if i < len(split_email)-1:
                    split_email[i+1] = ('x' * len(split_email[i+1]))
    for each_word in split_email:    
        for each_term in proprietary_terms:
            if each_term == each_word or each_term.title() == each_word: 
                if i > 0:
                    split_email[i-1] = ('x' * len(split_email[i-1]))
                split_email[i] = ('x' * len(each_word))
                if i < len(split_email)-1:
                    split_email[i+1] = ('x' * len(split_email[i+1]))

    return ' '.join(split_email)
```

Comment: Ah! Codecademy hasn't covered enumerate yet - that was new to me. Thanks for that. Though I still have one question if you don't mind. Is there any reason you can see why my code works for the "negative_words" list but not the "proprietary_terms" list? That's what was throwing me for a loop. If I comment out the proprietary list, the first part works just fine and adds the x's where they should be.

Comment: Your code has the same bug regarding `.title()` in both `negative_words` and `proprietary_terms`. Maybe your text doesn't have any negative words with title case.